# Dealing with outliers in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

Good day. The problem is the following - when trying to remove outliers from one of the columns in the table

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.stats import norm
from scipy import stats
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv("https://cf-courses-data.s3.us.cloud-object-storage.appdomain.cloud/IBM-DA0321EN-SkillsNetwork/LargeData/m2_survey_data.csv")
df["ConvertedComp"].plot(kind="box", figsize=(10,10))
z_scores = stats.zscore(df["ConvertedComp"])
abs_z_scores = np.abs(z_scores)
filtered_entries = (abs_z_scores < 3).all(axis=1)
new_df = df[filtered_entries]
```

the following error crashes.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AxisError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-133-7811da442811> in <module>
      4 z_scores
      5 abs_z_scores = np.abs(z_scores)
----> 6 filtered_entries = (abs_z_scores < 3).all(axis=1)
      7 #new_df = df[filtered_entries]

C:\ProgramData\WatsonStudioDesktop\miniconda3\envs\desktop\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_methods.py in _all(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
     44 
     45 def _all(a, axis=None, dtype=None, out=None, keepdims=False):
---> 46     return umr_all(a, axis, dtype, out, keepdims)
     47 
     48 def _count_reduce_items(arr, axis):

AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1
```

I would be grateful for your advice, ideas are almost over

Comment: An array of dimension 1 (e.g. a simple list of numbers) has only one axis: axis 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `zscore` is computed over only 1 column, so the result is a one-dimensional array

```py
z_scores = stats.zscore(df["ConvertedComp"])
new_df = df[np.abs(z_scores) < 3]
```

Now if you run `zscore` over multiple column, then your original code would have worked:

```py
z_scores = stats.zscore(df[["ConvertedComp", 'AnotherColumn']])
new_df = df[(np.abs(z_scores) < 3).all(axis=1)]
```